# How to highlight all span elements inside paragraphs using custom Angular directive?

Tags: html, angular, highlight

I have a task where I have to make custom directive and give CSS to all the spans inside paragraphs.

```
<p> fake <span>paragraph</span>. hello hello <span>fake</span> </p>
```

As I have mentioned span inside paragraph I want to highlight all the spans only. How can I do that as a being a newbie I just could not found out how can I do it.

Comment: but i want to do it using angular not CSS

Comment: Tags are just text in a file. You're talking about _elements_ here. Also, no need to write in code.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad. You're expected to make an effort and show your code. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: yes i know i respect everyone's time and efforts this is first time i am asking because i was just unable to produce that logic or it would be also be helpful i you can give me some hink from where can i start .